# python: what stops garbage collection

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I am trying to use `weakref.finalize` to handle the destruction of objects according to https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/weakref.html#comparing-finalizers-with-del-methods

However, the objects are never collected by Python's garbage collector, so I cannot test what I am doing. `weakref.finalize` is only called, when the script finishes (see `atexit`).

But I cannot find out, what blocks garbage collect.
See the following example:

```
import gc

from weakref import finalize, ref

import objgraph


def close_after_del(obj):

    def _cleaner(obj_):
        print("!object get's closed now")
        obj_.close()

    finalize(obj, _cleaner, obj)


print('open file')
fp = open('blub', 'w')
close_after_del(fp)

print('check for other references:')
objgraph.show_refs(fp)
print(gc.get_referrers(fp))
print('delete and collect it')
w_fp = ref(fp)
del fp
gc.collect()
print('check references again:')
print(gc.get_referrers(w_fp) if w_fp() is not None else "Weak reference is gone")
print("should be deleted by now but isn't")

objgraph.show_refs(w_fp)
```

`objgraph` only shows the weak references which should not matter (I only added it afterwards to check for references). `gc.get_referrers` shows a dictionary, is this related to `globals` or `locals`?

---

Solution according to @user2357112's answer:

```
from weakref import finalize


def close_after_del(proxy, fp):

    def _cleaner():
        print("!object gets closed now!")
        fp.close()

    finalize(proxy, _cleaner)


class Proxy():

    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.fp = fp


print('open file')
proxy = Proxy(open('blub', 'w'))
close_after_del(proxy, proxy.fp)

print('delete and collect it')
del proxy
import gc; gc.collect()
print("Got collected!")
```

Comment: `w_fp` is a weak reference object. It's never going to be `None`.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it `w_fp` -> `w_fp()`.

Comment: You're still getting the weak reference's referrers, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two issues here. First, in the `finalize` call:

```
finalize(obj, _cleaner, obj)
```

The callback and arguments shouldn't own references to the object being finalized. Since you've made `obj` one of the callback arguments directly, [the object can't be collected](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize):

> **Note:** It is important to ensure that *func*, *args* and *kwargs* do not own any references to *obj*, either directly or indirectly, since otherwise *obj* will never be garbage collected. In particular, *func* should not be a bound method of *obj*.

You might wonder how you're supposed to access the object, then. The answer is that you're not supposed to access the object. The object is supposed to be dead.

---

The second issue is that in the following line:

```
print(gc.get_referrers(w_fp) if w_fp is not None else "Weak reference is gone")
```

`w_fp` is the weak reference object, not its referent. You should be using `w_fp()`.

Comment: Okay, I understand that I need to use some proxy objects here.